# How can I convert SQL datetime to DD/MM/YYYY 22:00

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, type-conversion

I'm currently using `CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)` which gives me `dd/mon/yyyy hh:mm:ss:mmm`

I don't want seconds, milliseconds or character based months.

How can I do this in SQL?

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: See the table near the top of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) under the heading "Date and Time Styles"

Comment: @jadarnel27 thx, but thats where I got the convert from - it doesn't have the format I need.

Comment: @marc_s I am aware that list is complete and I would need string manip., hence the question. Was just looking for the quickest easiest way, which Andomar provided. Thanks!

Comment: If you could switch to SQL Server **2012**, you could use the "new" (long overdue!) [`FORMAT` function](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/the-format-function-in-sql-server-2012.html) for string formatting....

Comment: @marc_s hahahaha. Believe me I'd love to switch to 2012. However, it's not my call unfortunately!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pick the first 10 characters of format 101 (USA) and the first 5 of format 108 (time):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 108)
```

[Here's the list of convert formats at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: thanks. That works perfect. Good thinking using limited size varchars instead of substrings like other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to pick a different format from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).  If none of those formats work, build the string yourself with the `DATEPART()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I used this at first concatenating each DATEPART I needed, it was quite long. Andomars approach is ideal. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

Someone has to say it: consider doing the formatting at the client instead of with TSQL. That makes it easier to change the display if your user specifications ever change.

```
thisDate1.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Comment: This is what I planned to do initially. However, it's in a GridView so then I'd have to add RowDataBound and much more code than the 1 line in SQL. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
CONVERT(varchar,[datefield],104)+ ' '+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,[datefield],108),1,5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Check out the approach Andomar used with limited size varchars instead of using substrings!

Answer (score 0):

change the code to 106
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 106)